# Indoor Positioning System based on inertial sensors

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am a student,and I am developing an iOS  App to track indoor position. 
My idea is that from a given reference point (a known position), using inertial sensors in my iphone(such as accelerometer,Gyro,etc) track the phone when moving. And display on a indoor map（a simple indoor plan）when the user is going.

But the problem is that i have no idea how to combine  these sensors to give me an actual position?

Does someone has some experience that he can share with me about indoor positioning system using inertial sensors?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One Solution is to use [Bluetooth Beacons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon)
They connect to your iPhone's Bluetooth and based on their signal strengh you can estimate the distance to each one of them, so you can estimate your indoor position.

read more: [Indoor Positioning](http://tam.unige.ch/assets/documents/masters/bekkelien/Bekkelien_Master_Thesis.pdf)